# Question about an NHMV amplitude (in the book by Elvang et al) and its representation by plabic graphs

Tags: amplituhedron

I am looking at the NMHV amplitude with six particles with three positive helicities (particles 1,3,5). This amplitude is given in Eq.(10.1), which is

[3,1,6,5,4]+[3,2,1,6,5]+[3,2,1,5,4]

My question is: how are these terms related to plabic graphs? In other words, does each term corresponds to a specific plabic graph? If so, what is the correspondence? Or is each term corresponding to a combination of plabic graphs?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help with this!

Patrick